# Why is this a deadlock (MySQL using InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

SHOW INNODB ENGINE STATUS shows me this and calls it deadlock:

### LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK

100923 22:29:21
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 5335752, ACTIVE 0 sec, OS thread id 7992 inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1024, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 26, query id 14422 localhost 127.0.0.1 root update
insert into history_messagearguments (history_id, messageArguments_ORDER, messageArguments) values (69, 1, '1')
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 179145 n bits 304 index `fk_history_msgargs` of table `zvs_rkl_01_test`.`history_messagearguments` trx id 0 5335752 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 198 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000048; asc        H;; 1: len 6; hex 0000006fe7c5; asc    o  ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 5335748, ACTIVE 0 sec, OS thread id 6988 inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 500
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1024, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 25, query id 14424 localhost 127.0.0.1 root update
insert into history_messagearguments (history_id, messageArguments_ORDER, messageArguments) values (71, 0, '0')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 179145 n bits 304 index `fk_history_msgargs` of table `zvs_rkl_01_test`.`history_messagearguments` trx id 0 5335748 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 198 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000048; asc        H;; 1: len 6; hex 0000006fe7c5; asc    o  ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 179145 n bits 304 index `fk_history_msgargs` of table `zvs_rkl_01_test`.`history_messagearguments` trx id 0 5335748 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 198 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000048; asc        H;; 1: len 6; hex 0000006fe7c5; asc    o  ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)

I cannot see why this is a deadlock. There is no line "WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:" for transaction 1. If transaction 1 does not hold any locks, it cannot block anyone, so it cannot be part of a deadlock.

More theoretically, I cannot see condition 4 being satisfied as written here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Necessary_conditions

The way I see it, MySQL should let transaction 2 continue. After it completes, transaction 1 can then go on.

Here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851528/mysql-deadlock-explanation-needed) BrainCore wrote:

> Transaction 2 gets "stuck" behind Transaction 1's request, a la FIFO queue.

Can anyone point me to MySQL documentation to confirm this? I find it hard to believe that transactions are strictly executed in the order they arrive.

Before all the questions about the table layout, isolation level etc. show up: I do not ask for help right now about resolving the deadlock. I ask how to read the SHOW ENGINE STATUS OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

Read transactions 1 and 2:
Read from end to begining:

- what type and why: **lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting**
- what is blocked:RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 179145 n bits 304 index **fk_history_msgargs** of table zvs_rkl_01_test.history_messagearguments trx id 0 5335748
- WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED

InnoDB has problem with concurrent writes, especially if You insert data in the end of innodb table.

Comment: Can you cite a source for the claim that InnoDB has problem with concurrent writes if the insert if at the end of the table? Trying to do more research on this subject and it's hard to find info.

Comment: This post provides some additional evidence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730278/why-do-two-concurrent-delete-insert-statements-deadlock-on-an-empty-table.