# Two duplicate delete queries using primary key causing deadlock

Tags: mysql, locking, deadlock

I don't understand how two duplicate queries that each delete a single row against a single table using the primary key could have deadlocked. Can anyone explain?

It seems to me like one of the transactions should have gotten the lock and the other one would have to wait.

Here's the deadlock report, with the queries:

```
Fri Jun 01 2012 13:50:23
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3 1439005348, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 22419, OS thread id 1166235968 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 368
MySQL thread id 125597624, query id 3426379709 node3-int 10.5.1.119 application-devel updating
DELETE FROM `SessData` WHERE `SessKey` = '87EDF1479A275557AC8280DCA78AB886'
AND `Name` = 'CurrentRequestURL'

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3 1439005340, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 22419, OS thread id 1234073920 starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 0
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1216
MySQL thread id 125597622, query id 3426379705 node2-int 10.5.1.118 application-devel updating
DELETE FROM `SessData` WHERE `SessKey` = '87EDF1479A275557AC8280DCA78AB886'
AND `Name` = 'CurrentRequestURL'

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Here's the schema for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE  `application`.`SessData` (
  `SessKey` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `Value` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`SessKey`,`Name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

A few other details:

```
MySQL version: 4.1.21
Isolation level: REPEATABLE-READ
Character set on the the above columns: latin1
```

Comment: I think that's because you are deleting the same value in 2 transaction at the same time, and Innodb make rows-lock.

Comment: I thought I understood row locks and next-key locks. Please explain the scenario how this causes a deadlock. Please walk me through it.

Comment: I don't know why your deadlock report is not showing which locks are involved. Are you generating it with [SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-engine.html)?

Comment: @OldPro, that report is from MONyog, which gets its info from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS.

Comment: You need to get the full output which lists the locks held and the locks waiting. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1851528/712765) for an example.

Comment: @OldPro, I've seen the full report through SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS, and MySQL 4.1 doesn't show all that good stuff.

Comment: According to [the 4.1 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-monitors.html) you should be seeing specific lock status. If you're not then that's another problem.

Comment: MySQL 5.1 seems to have resolved this. Besides that, I learned that the deadlock reports don't show you other queries that may have occurred previously in the same transaction that may have created the lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using MySQL version 4.1.21.  4.1 is past its end-of-life and 4.1.21 isn't even the latest 4.1 version.  ([Extended support for MySQL 4.1 ended on December 31, 2009](http://dev.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html).) You should upgrade to at least 5.0.96, though you might as well come fully up-to-date to 5.5.25.  Failing that, an upgrade to [4.1.22](http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/mysql/4.1.22) would be the minimum you could do, though that probably won't fix your problem.

If you read the last example in the MySQL 4.1 [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-lock-modes.html) you see how this deadlock could occur if the row being deleted had previously been selected with a shared lock earlier in the transaction.  Likewise you could have acquired shared locks if there are foreign key constraints involved. The general problem is:

> A acquires a shared lock on x
>
> B waits for an exclusive lock on x.  It has to wait because of A's lock.
>
> A waits for an exclusive lock on x. It has to wait because B is ahead of it in the queue for the exclusive lock.

The way InnoDB handles locks, it will not upgrade A's shared lock to exclusive while B is waiting for the same exclusive lock, so this is a deadlock.

Alternarely, you may be hitting a bug when the two statements are both trying to delete a non-existent row (possibly just deleted by an immediately preceding third duplicate delete). Possibly related to:

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1866

Comment: I'm starting to agree that it's a bug, but there are no shared locks involved in the query, so the rest of your answer isn't relevant, though it is good to know.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who contributed. All of the great technical information helped convince me that it's probably a bug, and it's very possibly from a previous duplicate delete. I'll revisit after we upgrade to MySQL 5 to let everyone know if it is resolved with the new version, or I'll at least provide more information with the more detailed deadlock report in MySQL 5.

Answer (score 1):

As [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-locks-set.html) states:

> [`DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html) sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record the search encounters.

[Elsewhere](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html), it explains:

> Next-key lock: This is a combination of a record lock on the index record and a gap lock on the gap before the index record.

Since there are more than two locks involved, one connection might obtain one such lock whilst the other connection obtains the other; they will then be deadlocked waiting on eachother for the release of the lock which they do not hold.

Whilst you can disable gap locking by using the [`READ COMMITTED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-committed) isolation level, that does expose you to [phantom rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-next-key-locking.html).  You would be better to detect and reissue transactions that fail in the event of deadlock (as it happens in this case, the transaction that succeeds will delete the record and so the rolled-back transaction will not need to be reissued).

Comment: This might be the case, but it seems like MySQL would be smart enough to always perform the locks in the same order. Also, there seems to be an [exception](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read): `For locking reads (SELECT with FOR UPDATE or LOCK IN SHARE MODE), UPDATE, and DELETE statements, locking depends on whether the statement uses a unique index with a unique search condition, or a range-type search condition. For a unique index with a unique search condition, InnoDB locks only the index record found, not the gap before it.`

Comment: It does seem like if the exception applied in this case, there would be just one intention table lock and one exclusive row lock, yet, there seems to be two row locks involved. It's a puzzle. Maybe when the row doesn't exist, it must do a next key lock, which kicks off the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

I remember about a year ago helping someone troubleshoot a similar deadlock situation

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/trouble-deciphering-a-deadlock-in-an-innodb-status-log/3185#3185 (June 6, 2011)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/will-these-two-queries-result-in-a-deadlock-if-executed-in-sequence/3224#3224 (June 8, 2011)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/reasons-for-occasionally-slow-queries/3305#3305 (June 14, 2011)

Not to be overlooked is the fact that InnoDB deadlocks can be caused by SELECT statements under specific circumstances : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/are-innodb-deadlocks-exclusive-to-insert-update-delete/4470#4470 (August 8, 2011)

Please look at your `SHOW INNODB ENGINE STATUS\G`. Since you are using MySQL 4.1, the info is not as complete as it should in order to reveal a problem.

Notwithstanding, what is going on here? You are essentially [locking the Clustered Index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9613/877) (also called the [**gen_clust_index**](https://serverfault.com/a/239554/69271)). Two locks on the same exact row locks the same row and its gen_clust_index entry in the Clustered Index.

Only one can be locked exclusively. The other would be locked as exclusive but waiting. Of course, the last exclusive lock had to win. If both transactions timeout at the same time, this must have occurred in 50 seconds (default for innodb_lock_wait_timeout) for one or both.

So, who get's rolled back? According to your MySQL 4.1 `SHOW INNODB ENGINE STATUS\G`, `TRANSACTION (2)` would bite the dust and rollback because `TRANSACTION (1)` got a hold of the cluster key entry first.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Sorry, that was a face palm moment (http://www.profilebrand.com/funny-pictures/category/demotivational/114_face-palm-star-trek.gif). Both queries make exclusive locks. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: If transaction 2 was locked exclusively, why didn't it just update? I think that transaction 2 had the required locks and was actually before transaction 1 (judging by the thread and query id), so this makes sense. However, transaction 2 didn't complete and was rolled back instead. Thanks for the links, I learned a few things from them, but they didn't provide a solution in this case.

Comment: Here is a guess: TX1 and TX2 try to get an exclusive lock. TX2 tried first and TX1 tried second. They formed a deadly embrace for 50 seconds. TX2 timed out first. TX1 got control of the row and the cluster index entry, performed the DELETE. If TX2 retries, it would succeed and perform the DELETE again (nothing to delete at that point). This is one possible scenario.