# Why does mysql deadlock here?

Tags: mysql

Once in a while I get a mysql error. The error is

```
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

The query is

```
var res = cn.Execute("insert ignore into 
    Post(desc, item_id, user, flags)
    select @desc, @itemid, @userid, 0", 
    new { desc, itemid, userid });
```

How on earth can this query cause it? When googling I saw something about how querys that take long lock rows and cause this problem but no rows need to be touched for this insert

Comment: are you using myisam or innodb? Also, you need to know what was executed previously. AFAIK a deadlock is never coming from a single query.

Comment: Do you have any other queries running in the same connection?

Comment: @Sebas: I'm not sure, I have 4 instance running. This is the line that had a problem. Even if other rows were locked i dont know how this would fail. I suspect the other client did the same thing as i started them at the same time and every state last a few minutes

Comment: @ExplosionPills: No. I have another instance running but since its a different process the connection isn't shared

Comment: Well it is *possible* that the connection is shared, but maybe that's not the issue

Comment: @Sebas: I still have the stacktrace of the other. Its the same query/line. Also I am using innodb

Comment: @pst: I didn't check but I think item_id is unique and I do think two process tried to insert to the same table at the same time. -edit- reading link brb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deadlocks are caused by *inter-transaction* ordering and lock acquisitions. Generally there is one active transaction per connection (although different databases may work differently). So it is only in the case of *multiple connections* and thus *multiple overlapping transactions* that deadlocks can occur. A single connection/transaction cannot deadlock itself because there is no lock it can't acquire: it has it, or it can get it.

An insert deadlock can [be caused by a unique constraint](http://thushw.blogspot.com/2010/11/mysql-deadlocks-with-concurrent-inserts.html) - so check for a unique key constraint as a culprit. Other causes could be locks held for select "for update" statements, etc.

Also, ensure all transactions are *completed immediately* (committed or rolled back) after the operation(s) that require them. If a transaction is not closed in a timely manner it can lead to such deadlock behavior trivially. While ["autocommit"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) usually handles this, it can be changed and should not be relied upon: I recommend proper manual transaction usage.

See [Mysql deadlock explanation needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851528/mysql-deadlock-explanation-needed) and [How to Cope with Deadlocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-deadlocks.html) for more information. In this case, it is likely sufficient to "just try again".

Comment: My transactions last a while because it hits the server several times so it can take >200ms. I guess it make sense although I don't understand why its a deadlock when its the same query. Maybe it has to do with other transactions not being visible hmm.

Comment: @acidzombie24 If it's *only* that insert query, then I suspect it's the GAP as described in the linked article.